# How do I implement a javascript countdown synchronized over several clients using Firestore?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

One client can start the countdown and it would be visible on all other clients.

Ideally:

- An accuracy of 1 second is required
- Any client could pause or reset the countdown
- The countdown would continue if no clients were connected

I've tried storing the end time (when the countdown finishes) in Firestore, but I'm tripping over the fact that different clients have times that differ by a few seconds.

Answer (score 0):

I think these are the steps that are required

1 - When a user starts the count down, store the end time as a server timestamp

2 - When a user connects, query the stored time AND the server time stamp, calculate the difference and play the count down on screen

3 - if the difference is less than 0 (server time > stored time) you know the counter is finished.

No need to check user' local times

**UPDATE**

```
var sessionsRef = firebase.database().ref("Time");
sessionsRef.push({counter: ServerValue.TIMESTAMP});
```

Then just read it normally as you would read a child node with a listener.

Comment: Sounds like a plan. But how do you store and query the server timestamp?

Comment: Updated the answer.